# CSS unknown property "transform"

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with my stylesheet. I am trying to do some funny hover effects, but somehow I can't use transform. Can anyone help me? The error occurs down below the comment "view one".

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <head>
        <title>thomasteilmann.dk</title>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1><img src="teilmann.jpg" alt="Sick Logo" /></a></h1>
            Copyright Thomas Teilmann
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="view view-first">
            <img src="images/cosmic_art_icon.jpg"/>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Cosmic Art</h2>
                <p>A galleri of cosmic art made in Photoshop</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #21211f;
    width: 902px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 185px;
}

h1 img{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;

    margin: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 190px;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    width: 692px;
    margin-top: 65px;
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    font-family: Georgia, times, serif;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#content{
    width: 612px;
    background: #466287 url(images/corner.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia, times, serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 20px 60px 20px 30px;
}


img {
    border: none;
}

.form{
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    background: url(form1.jpg) no-repeat;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}


/*
 * View
*/

.view {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.view img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.view h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.view p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}


/* View one
*/

.view-first img {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first h2 {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first p {
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first a.info{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.view-first:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.view-first:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
.view-first:hover p {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-first:hover a.info {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Can u post your markup code?It will be good  for us to help you..

Comment: My only question is why i cant use transform in my stylesheet? :) but yes, if you need to see a couple of divs, then just a sec ;)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is and where  you are getting this message?

Comment: What browser(s) do you use to test this css3 feature?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmMQ/ You've got some problems in your markup (stray `</a>`, unclosed `<div>`).

Comment: Also, that `<link>` should probably be in the `<head>` element.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`transform` isn't a standard yet, so no browser supports it at present.

However, some browsers support vendor extensions based on the draft:

- `-ms-transform` in Internet Explorer 9
- `-moz-transform` in Mozilla browsers (most notably Firefox)
- `-webkit-transform` in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.)
- `-o-transform` in Opera
- Possibly others, I don't know.

Comment: A useful site for CSS3 styles is [css3please.com](http://www.css3please.com). It demos effects and gives css rules for common browsers (and specifies which rules apply for which browsers).

Answer (score 2):

just use this css inside your css code.Remember transform  does not work in all browsers.

```
.view-first:hover {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use vendor specific styles for the transitions, for example:

```
#id_of_element {
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;

}
```

You can read more about transitions and transformations here - http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/